# Is there any touch event for the table view in cocoa touch

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, uitableview

In my app there is a table view and it have some image view in it .Actually 4 image view in a row.Is there any touch event for the table view so that i am able to select any image view inside the table view and then do some functionalities with it.Please help.Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Christy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a [gesturerecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html) to each of the subviews. Once a gesture of that certain recognizer was detected (tab, swipe, pinch, pan, swipe, rotation, longtab or custom (by subclassing)), a targets selector will be called.

```
for(UIImageView *imgView in imageViews){
    UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                                                          action:@selector(handleTapFrom:)];
    [imgView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    recognizer.delegate = self;
    [recognizer release];
}
```

Comment: but can i do it for the image view present inside the table view

Comment: you can assign it to any view